# Using a line integral to finding a function for the distance between two points on a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, line-integrals

Per the title, suppose in R 3 we have a unit sphere. Two vectors intersect that sphere at two points.

I know the distance between two points can be found as a function of the angle between the two vectors using a cross product, or with trig given the angle however, I'm looking for a line integral solution that can be scaled to a similar structure in R 4.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: AFAIK the distance is the radius times the angle between the two points measured relative to the center (the same formula as for the 3D sphere), and the angle is the arccos of the dot product of the normalized coordinates, the sum of the products of the Cartesian
components.